# Simple_form association multiple

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I am using a simpleform collection association input, as checkboxes in order to allow users to choose 1+ items from a list as part of an order. The list has a has_and_belongs_to_many association with the overall order.  I want them to be able to do multiple of the same items, however. So I would want a small number input next to each checkbox. I can handle the javascript, I am just wondering how to do this with simpleform, if its even possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you write a custom input for this specific task.

You would need to put it in # app/inputs/your_input.rb for Simple_form to automatically pick it up.

Then in the file :

```
class YourInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base
  def input
     # Your code here, but I just pasted the example that adds something after the existing field already as a reference.
    "$ #{@builder.text_field(attribute_name, input_html_options)}".html_safe
  end
end
```

and in the form :

```
f.input :money, as: :your
```

In case of checkbox, the method name will change to "check_boxes" from "input"